# Group (Find) the similar columns in to a group and sum the values of each group in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to group the columns with the condition that the (SN) row with similar dates are put in a group with the date in ascending order and sum up the each group values of table2 based on these groups.

Table1:

```
 SN A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
    FA1 26-Sep-50   26-Nov-64   26-Nov-64   26-Nov-64   30-Oct-40   30-Oct-40   26-Nov-64   26-Nov-64   26-Nov-64   26-Nov-64   26-Nov-64
    FA2 27-Apr-24   2-Dec-27    31-Jul-29   6-Dec-24    7-Mar-33    13-Jul-21   31-Jul-29   31-Jul-29   31-Jul-29   31-Jul-29   31-Jul-29
    FA3 21-Mar-08   25-Dec-10   25-Dec-10   25-Dec-10   28-Sep-13   28-Sep-13   25-Dec-10   25-Dec-10   25-Dec-10   25-Dec-10   25-Dec-10
    FA4 4-Dec-27    27-Nov-14   27-Nov-14   27-Nov-14   31-May-21   31-May-21   27-Nov-14   27-Nov-14   27-Nov-14   27-Nov-14   27-Nov-14
```

Table2:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
5   2   3   4   4   3   2   1   1   2   8
```

OUTPUT table:

```
SN   Group1     Group2      Group3     Group4    Group5     G_Sum1  G_Sum2  G_Sum3  G_Sum4  G_Sum5
FA1 30-Oct-40   26-Sep-50   26-Nov-64                          7       5    23      
FA2 13-Jul-21   27-Apr-24   2-Dec-27  31-Jul-29 7-Mar-33       3       9    2         17    4
FA3 21-Mar-08   25-Dec-10   28-Sep-13                          5      23    7       
FA4 27-Nov-14   31-May-21   4-Dec-27                           23      7    5
```

Comment: For EX: SN: FA1, Column E & F as 30-Oct-40, so the Group1 is  30-Oct-40 and pull the values  E(4) & F(3) from Table2 and sumup (4+3) as G_Sum1

Comment: Transpose your data for both tables and merge them. Then calculating the sum is trivial. You can always transpose it back.  In the current format this would be an incredibly ugly task.

Comment: Its a huge file and there are number of columns in the table

Comment: Define huge? And at any rate it doesn't matter the data structure isn't conducive to analysis.

Comment: If you post data as a data step I'll mock up some code. To meet SO rules you should also post what you've tried.

Comment: @Reeza Actually, I think your first comment is a good answer, and should be posted as such.  The right approach to this is to transpose - so that's the answer to 'how do I do this'.  Questions about' how do I approach this problem' are okay, with enough detail - but they don't need to be answered with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpose your data for both tables and merge them. Then calculating the sum is trivial. You can always transpose it back. In the current format this would be an incredibly ugly task.

Proc Transpose will transpose the data so you don't need to know the number of columns. If you try to work with the data in this form you'll have to predetermine the maximum number of groups you'll need, whereas in a long form it can be dynamically calculated.

Comment: Ok, I will give a try